# Overriding default <%=%> in JSP to prevent XSS Hack

Tags: java, jsp, xss

There is web project with lost `<%=%>` in it, which are not XSS safe! Is there any approach which can be used to fix them all?

If you have jsp web projects with lots of %{} you can change the EL resolver functionality to override the default ELResolver and make `${}` XSS safe. Please see https://github.com/pukkaone/webappenhance

Is there a same way for `<%=>` ?! Can we override the functionality of `<%=%>` the same way as `${}` ??

I see some guides at [Java 5 HTML escaping To Prevent XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333586/java-5-html-escaping-to-prevent-xss).

Comment: Do you mean printing the expressions in jsp using this statement `<%=%>` ?

Comment: yes! They use <%=%> to print in jsp

Comment: So you need to avoid xss while printing the values in jsp . this may be unrelated to your question . please see [How to avoid java codes in jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: So it is better to use `c:out` tag instead of it . and for your question [see this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339439/how-to-avoid-xss-in-this-cout)

Comment: @sankrish the problem is that the project is already developed (long time ago). They wrongly, used `<%=%>`. Of course we can change all `<%=%>` to `c:out` but needs lots of works, this is why I am looking for other solutions

Comment: using `jstl` would be the straight forward approach . Any reasons for your worrying about `<%=%>` expression. how they are vulnerable , do you print any user inputs or strings inside it ?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. `<%= expr %>` is a basic construct that prints the value as is; someone may *need* it to dump raw HTML snippets

```
<%= article.getBodyHtml %>
```